# Single page site with history.js

Tags: theme-development, templates, javascript, template-hierarchy

I'm developing a single page site that shows each page on the front page, like so:

```
                                *-----------------*
                                | Home            |
                                |                 |
                                |                 |
                                |                 |
                                *-----------------*
                                | About           |
                                |                 |
                                |                 |
                                |                 |
                                *-----------------*
                                | Work            |
                                |                 |
                                |                 |
                                |                 |
                                *-----------------*
```

And I'm using history.js to alter the URL structure based on which section is visible in the viewport. Everything controlling this output is in my theme's `index.php`, and mirrored in the `pages.php` file. Which I'm sure there's a better way to do that, but I've no idea what it might be.

I want all pages that aren't /, /about or /work to redirect to the homepage (client doesn't want to use 404), another thing I don't know how to go about setting up.

I know I could put a PHP redirect in the `single.php` file and an `include()` in the `pages.php` but that doesn't strike me like the best option.

Comment: How many pages are we talking about?  If you just have /about, /work and web root, why not set up an htaccess redirect to web root for anything not those three?

Comment: Well, It's 5 pages in total. And I hadn't considered that, dunno why not. Thanks! But what about the mirrored content in `index.php` and `page.php`?

Comment: Is it even necessary to have anything in page.php if everything is truly in index.php?  If you don't have a page.php, it will be bypassed in the template hierarchy and index.php will be loaded.

Comment: Removed page.php and it works, thanks! Never built a template without the standard files.

Comment: Sure thing, in the future you can refer to: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy.  Did you get the .htaccess part figured out?

Comment: Haven't tried yet, but it shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

As per comments: if you want all pages to redirect to the `index.php` template anyway, it's not necessary to put redirects in templates like `page.php` and `single.php`. You can simply remove those templates and the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) will handle it for you.